# Factors of 2* : a way to know if integer factorises by 4, 8, 16... is this valid?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring

Are my findings valid? If so they must be on some maths logic that is beyond me...

So I was quizzing my kids (7&9) on seeing if a number was divisible by 3. They then asked me about 4 but the standard 'trick' (last 2 digits are divisible by 4) is not 'easy' for them so I observed the following:

On any length number:

$F$ = Penultimate digit

$V$ = last digit

If $(F + \frac{V}{2})$ is EVEN,

Then the original number is divisible by $4$.

Eg

$36 = 3 + 6/2$ which is even

$46 = 4 + 6/2$ which is odd

Intrigued I tested this for $8$

$F =$ antepenultinate digit

$V =$ last $2$ digits

If $(F + \frac{V}{2*2})$ is Even

Then the original number is divisible by $8$

Eg

$816 = 8 + \frac{16}{4}$ = even

$820 = 8 + \frac{20}{4}$ = odd

I tested again for $16$ and the pattern continued,

So

$2^x$ Is a factor of INTEGER if...

$F = INTEGER [INTEGER.Length-x+1]$ (single digit)

$V =\text{last }(x - 1) \text{ digit(s)}$

If $F + \frac{V}{2^x}$ = EVEN

Then

$2^x$ is a factor of INTEGER

Was I right? Is there a proof?

What logic is this based on - simple times tables?

Comment: This is hard to read, but I think it works.  The point is that, for even numbers, your expression $F+\frac V2$ alternates in parity, as does divisibility by $4$.

Comment: Yes i appreciate that the text sucks - i couldnt find how to format here on my phone - I apologise

Comment: $x$ is divisible by $2^n$ if $x=a\times10^n+b$ for some integers $a$ and $b$ with $b$ divisible by $2^n$.  Your test is equivalent to $b$ being divisible by $2^n$

Comment: @lulu thanks I will google "alternates in parity" - thanks!

Comment: "alternates" in parity just means that the sequence goes Even, Odd, Even, Odd, Even, Odd , ...  (well, it could also go Odd, Even, Odd, Even...).  But I'm not sure I answered your question.  I thought you were just asking about divisibility by $4$.  If you were asking about something else, my comment might not be relevant.

Comment: @Henry so the 10n takes care of the shifting column - cool - thanks!